# Export MySQL Table to .tsv from a remote server without using `INTO INFILE`

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, csv

I have a very large table on an Amazon RDS instance that I need to export as a .tsv with specific settings.  I cannot use `INTO OUTFILE` on the RDS instance.  So I must export the table onto the local drive of the server I'm logging into the RDS MySQL instance with.

I have specific settings I need to specify for the .tsv. They are:

1. terminate with \t
2. wrap with nothing
3. escape with a backslash
4. null values are blank

How do I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this-

```
mysql -uroot -proot -h "mysql.host.url" -N -B -e "select * from world.city" | sed 's/NULL/ /g' > test.tsv
```

-N tells it not to print column headers. -B is "batch mode", and uses tabs to separate fields. NULL is replaced by space.

For 100 GB databases , this may help-

```
 mysql -uroot -proot -h "mysql.host.url" -N -B -e "select * from world.city" > test.tsv
 sed 's/NULL/ /g' < test.tsv > new.tsv
```

But i recommend For huge databases you should use ETL Tools.

Comment: This works great on tables that fit in memory on the server you're querying from ... but doesn't work in my case because it loads the results from the query into memory, and the table is 100GB ... exceeding memory on all my machines.  It fails when memory runs out.

Comment: Perhaps writing the query results to disk and then performing the find replace will work.

Comment: @T.BrianJones for large size database, you should use ETL tools

Comment: The solution I ended up using in a pinch, was to do batch queries ( using LIMIT and OFFSET ). Then I combined the output into one .tsv using CAT on the local server.

Comment: 1) For large tables you can now use `--quick` to stream results from the server. 2) This command will replace newlines with `\\n` and backslashes with `\\\`, so be careful when loading the data.

Comment: Please enote --batch is implied when output is redirected. So `mysql db -e 'query' > out.tsv` will output a TSV output while the same command without redirection will print a tabular output.